# set div width to ul list size

Tags: html, css

I Have:

```
<div class="div1">
    <ul>
        <li><input type="button" value="val1"></li>
        <li ><input type="button" value="val2"></li>
        <li ><input type="button" value="val2"></li>
        <li ><input type="button" value="val2"></li>
        <li ><input type="button" value="val2"></li>
        <li ><input type="button" value="val2"></li>
        <li ><input type="button" value="val2"></li>
        <li ><input type="button" value="val2"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.div1{
    position:absolute;
    height:30px;
    width:auto;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-15px;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%);
    border:1px solid #f7f7f7;
    display: inline-block; //inline
}
.ul li{
    margin-right:5px;
    box-shadow: 2px 3px 3px #666666;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

I simply want the width of `div1` to extend based on amount of `li` size (FYI: li amount is random).

If I set div `width: 100px // or something` then `li` overflows the div container. and if i try to set div `width: auto` still the same.

Also I noticed one thing in my browser inspect mode, that if i remove left:50% then it works just fine, but the position of the box come to left and I need to keep the element centered

All replies are much appreciated :)

Comment: You want to create buttons list centered horizontally and vertically in window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove height and width of div1. They will have default values.
And do not put dot `.` before ul selector in the css rule. `ul` is element, not class.

```css
.div1{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-15px;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%);
    border: 1px solid #f70000;
    display: inline-block; //inline
}
ul li{
    margin-right:5px;
    box-shadow: 2px 3px 3px #666666;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
    <ul>
        <li><input type="button" value="val1"></li>
        <li ><input type="button" value="val2"></li>
        <li ><input type="button" value="val2"></li>
        <li ><input type="button" value="val2"></li>
        <li ><input type="button" value="val2"></li>
        <li ><input type="button" value="val2"></li>
        <li ><input type="button" value="val2"></li>
        <li ><input type="button" value="val2"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: okay I just tried it but still having the same issue, and I noticed one thing in my browser inspect mode, that if i remove `left:50%` then it works just fine, but the position of the box come to left and I need to keep the element centered.

Comment: what browser you use?

Comment: Figured out the problem, posted my own answer see if you have anything to say.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood the question, but if I set the height to auto, not 30px, there were no overflow when I tested it at least

```
.div1{
    position:absolute;
    height:auto; // CHANGED THIS LINE
    width:auto;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-15px;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%);
    border:1px solid #f7f7f7;
    display: inline-block; //inline
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Did you try do not set `width` attribute? Or you can just specify `min-width` if you need any size of the `div` at least.

Note: `inline-block` should take width of its content

2) I am not sure, but your `li`s actually do not use width as much and if you add much more of them they should obviously expand the `height` of the `div`, so you should probably use `min-height` property or do not specify any `height`.

```
<div class="div1">
    <ul>
        <li><input type="button" value="val1"></li>
        <li ><input type="button" value="val2"></li>
        <li ><input type="button" value="val2"></li>
        <li ><input type="button" value="val2"></li>
        <li ><input type="button" value="val2"></li>
        <li ><input type="button" value="val2"></li>
        <li ><input type="button" value="val2"></li>
        <li ><input type="button" value="val2"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know why But I just figured out that the problem was in `translate()` so in order to keep my div container centered and extend the width of the box to auto.

A simple and clean way:

```
.div1{
    margin: 30px auto;
    border: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
    display: table;
}
```

As it says: one bow two kills (clean and quick)